# Why are violin string so expensive?

Tags: strings, violin

What exactly is about violin strings that make them so expensive in comparison to guitar strings? Is there something about the manufacturing process that is just more expensive?

Does it have something to do with bowed strings vs plucked strings?

Comment: Probably has far more to do with market forces. Thousands more guitar strings must be sold than violin strings. At very least, I think guitar strings are more sacrificial.

Comment: @Tim not in the least.  Take a look at guidot's answer.  Guitar strings are cheap throwaways compared with violin, cello, bass, and even elec.bass strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually see not much more than the name *string* they have in common. While I have only superficial knowledge of guitar strings they seem to have simple homogeneous structure like nickel-plated steel, which is easily mass-produced. If you choose the same material for violin, prices don't seem to be significantly different. But nearly no one uses them. Typical violin strings have a core/wrapping structure and the wrapping can easily be something like silver wire. Even if the rosin applied to the bow significantly contributes to the friction necessary for torsion vibration, a somewhat rough surface of the string supports it.

Comment: Just to add in, here is what a string looks like under a microscope http://mdarnton.tumblr.com/post/12184117752/a-dominant-violin-d-string-under-the-microscopic